# java generics , clarification on extends and super

Tags: java, generics

This is the class definition of CompletionStage

```
public interface CompletionStage<T> {
...
}
```

And this is the method thenApply

```
public <U> CompletionStage<U> thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn);
```

My questions is:  Why is it taking *? super T* as the first argument of Function... shouldn't it be *? extends T* since any subClass of T can be cast as T ? And any super class of T cannot be cast as T ??

Comment: `fn` *consumes* the result of the stage. As such, it can be a function which accepts T or any supertype of T, since then any T it receives is also an instance of that supertype. It can't require a *subtype* of T, because there is no guarantee that the result of the stage will be of that specific type.

Comment: Stupid title. I fixed it for your.

Answer (score 2):

I'd approach this by asking, which signature would make most sense? There are three options:

- `Function<? extends T, ? extends U>`
- `Function<T, ? extends U>`
- `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`

First of all, `? extends T` does not include `T`. So you could not pass `Function<T, U>` to `CompletionStage<T>` which would have been unexpected. So `? extends T` is not the best choice.

This leaves us with simply `T` or `? super T`.

Simply `T` would work for `Function<T, U>`, just as `? super T`. But which is better? `? super T` would allow you to apply functions with arguments which are `T` or superclasses of `T`. This is much more flexible compared to simply `T` since you could use more generic functions. For instance, you could do `CompletionStage<Integer>.thenApply(Function<Number, String>)` which would not be possible with simple `T`. `? super T` also does not seem to have any drawbacks, at least I don't see any.

So from my point of view, `? super T` is clearly a better choice.